# ¿Cómo crear una lista, la cual sus valores están relacionados con otras listas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista

Quisiera hacer una lista `población` , la cual arranca con `población[0] = 100000` y luego quiero ir agregando items dependiendo de otras listas, `nac[]` y `mort[]`.

Por ejemplo:

```
nac[0] = poblacion[0] * n_t
mort[0] = poblacion[0] * m_t
```

para el `poblacion[1] = poblacion[0] + nac[1] + mort[1]`

```
pop = 100000
t = 50 # tiempo
t_m = 0.008
t_n = 0.01

poblacion = []
aux = []
nac = []
mort = []

a = pop * t_n
b = pop * t_m

poblacion.append(pop)
nac.append(b)
mort.append(a)

print(poblacion,nac,mort)

for i in range(t):

    #poblacion.clear()
    i = pop
    poblacion.append(i)

    i = a
    nac.append(i)

    i = b
    mort.append(i)

for j, v, x in zip(range(t), range(t), range(t)):

    j = poblacion[j]+nac[t]-mort[j]
    poblacion.append(j)

    v = poblacion[v]*t_n
    #nac.clear()
    nac.append(v)

    x = poblacion[x]*t_m
    mort.append(x)



print(poblacion)
print(nac)
print(mort)
print(aux)
print(len(poblacion))
print(len(nac))
print(len(mort))
print(len(aux))
```

No se si alguien tuviera un ejemplo de como hacerlo, había pensado en hacerlo con recursividad pero la verdad que no tengo mucha experiencia.

Answer (score 1):

Si lo he entendido, no necesitas complicarte demasiado, simplemente debes desplazar el cálculo de la población:

```
pop = 100000
t = 5 # tiempo
t_m = 0.008
t_n = 0.01


población = []
nac = []
mort = []

for _ in range(t + 1):
    población.append(pop)
    nacimientos = int(round(pop * t_n))
    muertes = int(round(pop * t_m))
    pop = pop + nacimientos - muertes
    mort.append(muertes)
    nac.append(nacimientos)

print(población)
print(nac)
print(mort)
```

> ```
> [100000, 100200, 100400, 100601, 100802, 101004]
> [1000, 1002, 1004, 1006, 1008, 1010]
> [800, 802, 803, 805, 806, 808]
> ```

El cálculo en este caso es:

```
    población[0] = pop
    poblacion[1] = poblacion[0] + nac[0] - mort[0]
    poblacion[2] = poblacion[1] + nac[1] - mort[1]
    ...
```

Otra opción sería que fuera:

```
    población[0] = pop
    poblacion[1] = poblacion[0] + nac[1] - mort[1]
    poblacion[2] = poblacion[1] + nac[2] - mort[2]
    ...
```

pero en este caso lo apropiado es que `mort[0]` y `nac[0]` sean ambos 0:

```
pop = 100000
t = 5 # tiempo
t_m = 0.008
t_n = 0.01


población = [pop]
nac = [0]
mot = [0]

for _ in range(t):
    nacimientos = int(round(pop * t_n))
    muertes = int(round(pop * t_m))
    pop = pop + nacimientos - muertes
    población.append(pop)
    mot.append(muertes)
    nac.append(nacimientos)

print(población)
print(nac)
print(mot)
```

> ```
> [100000, 100200, 100400, 100601, 100802, 101004]
> [0, 1000, 1002, 1004, 1006, 1008]
> [0, 800, 802, 803, 805, 806]
> ```

Asumo que estás trabajando con una población, tasa de natalidad y tasa de mortalidad, por eso he redondeado al entero más cercano dado que en principio no existen individuos medio nacidos o medio muertos ni poblaciones con una fracción de un individuo :). Además resto `mort` en vez de sumarlo a la población.

Comment: Te hago una consulta: en "for i in  range..." la variable i no la usas para calcular cada lista, es solo para recorrer el loop?

Comment: Si, de hecho debería ser _ y no i, para seguir las convenciones de estilo. Como el incremento es continuo y en una unidad no necesitamos el timpo para calcular, basta con partir de los datos anteriores. Es simplemente aplicar la fórmula que tu mismo das, `nac[0] = poblacion[0] * n_t`
`mort[0] = poblacion[0] * m_t`, no tiene sentido indizar con i, basta con desplazar el cálculo de la población como ya comentaba reasignando a `pop`... Si no es la salida que buscas, deberías editar la pregunta y añadir las listas de salida esperadas. Un saludo,

Answer (score 1):

Son varias lineas a corregir, por ejemplo, el primer **for** no es necesario, pues estás llenando con 50 elementos iguales las 3 listas. En el segundo **for** vuelves y agregas otros 50 elementos mas. No es necesario iterar por las 3 listas.

Yo lo dejaría así:

```
pop = 100000
t = 50 # tiempo
t_m = 0.008
t_n = 0.01

poblacion = [pop]
nac = [0]
mort = [0]

print(poblacion)
print(nac)
print(mort)

for i in range(t):    
    nac.append(poblacion[i] * t_n)
    mort.append(poblacion[i] * t_m)
    poblacion.append(poblacion[i] + nac[i-1] - mort[i-1])

    print("{0:d}: Pob: {1:.0f} - Nac: {2:.0f} - Mort: {3:.0f}".format(i, poblacion[i], nac[i], mort[i]))

print(len(poblacion), len(nac), len(mort))
```